# Is it possible to keep a strict type argument on Promise when using an import() with a computed string?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I have a question regarding imports with a computed string.
I noticed they seem to be typed as `Promise<any>`, but I'd like to know if there's a better way to handle this, so that they could be still typed as `Promise<typeof ...>`.

I will try to present the issue with minimal and isolated code snippets first and then provide a use case (to give an example).

---

When I write an *import* like this:

```
import(`@/i18n/locales/${language}`)
```

I have the impression that the type of `import(...)` becomes `Promise<any>`.
I deduce this by isolating this *import* within the assignment of a variable:

```
const x = () => import(`@/i18n/locales/${'en'}`);
```

```
const x: () => Promise<any>
```

But, when I write:

```
const x = () => import("@/i18n/locales/en");
```

Then:

```
const x: () => Promise<typeof import("/foo/bar/src/i18n/locales/en")>
```

In the case where it involves *string interpolation* that is unpredictable, I understand the `Promise<any>`.
But in some cases, I think that a similar interpolation can be typed and controlled.

For example, using a sum type:

```
type LanguageFlag = "en" | "fr" | "it";
const LANGUAGES: LanguageFlag[] = ["en", "fr", "it"];
```

So, I would like my *imports* to keep the correct typing on the `Promise<>` type argument.

For instance:

```
// * ... @/i18n/locales/schema

export default {
  _infos: {
    lng: '',
    label: ''
  },

  navbar: {
    assistance: ''
  },

  auth: {
    login: '',
    logout: '',
    signup: ''
  }
  // * ...
} as const;
```

```
//====================
// * ... Types
//====================

//------------------------
// * ... JSON
//------------------------

type JSONPrimitiveLeafs = string | number | boolean | null;
type JSONLeafs = JSONPrimitiveLeafs | JSONPrimitiveLeafs[];

type TypedLeafsJSONData<LeafsTypes extends JSONLeafs, AllowObjArrays extends 'ALLOW_OBJ_ARRAYS' = never> = {
  [_: string]: TypedLeafsJSONData<LeafsTypes> | (AllowObjArrays extends never ? never : TypedLeafsJSONData<LeafsTypes>[]) | LeafsTypes;
};

//------------------------
// * ... Utilitary types
//------------------------

type MakeHomogeneousValuesObjType<Obj extends object, ObjValuesType> = {
  [K in keyof Obj]: Obj[K] extends object ? MakeHomogeneousValuesObjType<Obj[K], ObjValuesType> : ObjValuesType;
};

//------------------------
// * ... Locales
//------------------------

import VOCAB_SCHEMA from '@/i18n/locales/schema';

type LocalesObjKey = LanguageFlag;
type VocabObjValue = string;
type VocabBase = typeof VOCAB_SCHEMA;

type VocabType = MakeHomogeneousValuesObjType<VocabBase, VocabObjValue>;
type NextInternationalMagic = {
  default: VocabType;
};
type NextInternationalLazyLoadFn = () => Promise<NextInternationalMagic>;

type LanguageFlag = "en" | "fr" | "it";

type LocalesObjEntity = [LocalesObjKey, NextInternationalLazyLoadFn];
type LocalesObj = Record<LocalesObjKey, NextInternationalLazyLoadFn>;
type LocalesGetterConfigObjTypeConstraint = Record<LanguageFlag, () => Promise<TypedLeafsJSONData<VocabObjValue>>>;

//====================
// * ... Generator
//====================

const LANGUAGES: LanguageFlag[] = ["en", "fr", "it"];

export const GENERATED_LOCALES_OBJ = Object.fromEntries(
  LANGUAGES.map((language) => [language, () => import(`@/i18n/locales/${language}`)] satisfies LocalesObjEntity)
) as LocalesObj satisfies LocalesGetterConfigObjTypeConstraint;
```

Here, I am a bit disappointed by this line:

```
  LANGUAGES.map((language) => [language, () => import(`@/i18n/locales/${language}`)] satisfies LocalesObjEntity)
```

Since the values of `language` are predictable:

> (parameter) language: "en" | "fr" | "it"

I would have liked having a consistent `satisfies LocalesObjEntity`.
But since this import is typed as `Promise<any>`, the *satisfies* operator is currently completely useless.

If the `Promise` type argument could be: `<typeof .../en ; typeof .../fr ; typeof .../it>` the *satisfies* operator could validate or invalidate the imports.

So, I would like to know: is there a compilation flag I could add, or could I be even stricter and still allowing the possibility of using string interpolations?

Thank you in advance for your responses!